# Ionic 2 : popToRoot() doesn't redirect to root component ( home page )

Tags: ionic2

Every thing work fine in this function, but **this.nav.popToRoot()** doesn't work in that location.
If I move it to the beginning of the function it works correctly.
Doesn't any one has a logical explanation for this.

Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Here is the code in a booking.ts component:

```
book(){
  let newReservation = {
    _id: this.room._id,
    from: this.details.from.substring(0,10),
    to: this.details.to.substring(0,10)
  }

  let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: "Booking room..."
  });

  loading.present();

  this.roomsService.reserveRoom(newReservation).then((res) => {
    loading.dismiss();
    console.log("Room reserved successfully ... ");
    this.nav.popToRoot();
  }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It happens the same to me, but i managed to replace the whole history stack, in my case after a certain point i don't need to keep the history stack, this is how i did it:

```
this.navCtrl.setPages([
  { page: RootPageHere }
]);
```

Works inside of a promise then function.