# ionic 2 Redirect to another page if condition true from html page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am in the need to get redirect another page from my html page in ionic 2,
Let me tell the system setup on my local machine-

```
******************************************************
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
******************************************************
```

When some html page get compile, redirect it after some lines of code from html. I know how to [redirect from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786222/showing-a-different-tab-with-an-if-statement-on-ionic-2)

```
if(1 > 2){
  this.rootpage = AuthTab;
}else{
  this.rootpage = AppTab;
}
```

but now I need to get redirect from html page when some condition get true, something like this-

```
 <div *ngIf="((condition=='true')&& !(condition =='true'))">
   <div class="myclass">
      <div class="myclass">
         <div class="myclass">
            <div class="myclass">
               <div class="myclass">
                  <div class="myclass">
                     <div class="myclass" (click)="somePage($event, param1, param2)"> 
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

As I have redirect on click, but i want to do the same without click

```
(<div class="myclass" (click)="somePage($event, param1, param2)"> )
```

See *mypage.ts* file as

```
somepage(event, param1,param2) {
    this.navCtrl.push(ViewPage, {
      Prm  : param1, 
      Prm2 : param2
    });
  }
```

In above ts file no need to fear about variable declaration, I have did that.

Also have seen this list of URL:-

1. [Ionic 2 : popToRoot() doesn't redirect to root component ( home page )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455399/ionic-2-poptoroot-doesnt-redirect-to-root-component-home-page)
2. https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5484

**Hope for help!**

Comment: Is that line <div *ngIf="((condition=='true')&& !(condition =='true'))"> part of some component?

Comment: This is html tag which is used to check for condition, and is there in page.html

Comment: Can you maybe explain what your trying to acomplish? If what condition is true, and at what exactly point do you want to redirect the user?

Comment: Yes, if that condition is true, i wanted to redirect on some other page.

Comment: So why checking in your template? When does the condition becomes truelike?

Comment: See, there are many thing along to get accomplished, I can't go back to controller , redirect on some page and come back again, so i did so.

Comment: But when does the condition because true-like?

Comment: there is an array from where I am getting data, there is an attribute call TYPE="THML" it get true, and it is being true also, just wanted to know how that even will get fire without click ....

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use "Eventemitter"

Write a event function in ts and write another function which monitors your condition and calls this event function once the conditon is true
so here you are essentially calling event.notify yourself when the condition turns true

catch the event fired by you using another function where you actually move from one page to another

EventEmitter is very useful 
just read on it 
It can be used in many ways

Comment: I can but I am in such a scenario that even can get occur without any click or something like that.